# Migrate Dash App to separate Data Studio Reports

Tags: python, google, cloud, google-data-studio

I would like to know how can I do this and if it is makes sense to you.

I have a Dash app written in Python in which:

```
1) I make the connection to my Databases (Python).
2) Perform several queries in SQL to obtain the data I need (Python). 
3) If need, manipulate the query response with Python to obtain the 
   desired metric (Python).
4) Build the plots (Python, Plotly, Dash)
```

This Dash App is on a server and I pay for it.

---

On the other hand, I am evaluating to migrate this App to something else, replacing the previous items with:

```
1) Make the connection to the databases with Google BigQuery
2) Perform the queries in SQL to obtain the data I need with Google 
   BigQuery.
3) If I need, manipulate the query response with Python to obtain the 
   desired metric. 
4) Build the plots or dashboard with Google Data Studio.
```

So, is it possible? I have some question about each point:

```
1) To make the connection to my databases with Google BigQuery? Do I 
   have to migrate my datasets to Google Cloud to use them?
2) I assume that you can perform queries with SQL normally with Google 
   BigQuery, I need to do several JOINS,etc.
3) Can I add a Python script to manipulate my data in Google BigQuery?
```

So Instead of having an app I will have several reports on Google Data Studio.